# Android ImageView link to a Website

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want an image to link to a website. I know this is possible, my knowledge of Java however is very basic. The rest of the app is already done, I just need this to finish it.
I already have the permissions added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/uccw_skins_icon" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonRepairSkin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/install_skin" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/reclamebanners" />

   //load code while onCreate calls
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is MainActivity.java:

```
package penhoat.design.gs5free;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// change this to your apk skin name
private static final String UCCW_TEST_SKIN_APK = "gs5free.apk";



// Do not touch code that follows unless you know what you are doing
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonRepairSkin).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showInstallableSkins();
                }

            });

}

private class RepairSkinAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Processing...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... nothing) {
        String SDCARD_MYAPK_APK = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + File.separator + "my_temporary_skin_apk.apk";
        deleteOldSkin(SDCARD_MYAPK_APK);
        saveSkinToSdCard(SDCARD_MYAPK_APK);
        startAppInstaller(SDCARD_MYAPK_APK);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
private void showInstallableSkins() {
    if (isSDcardAvailable()) {
        new RepairSkinAsyncTask().execute();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "SD card not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}

private void deleteOldSkin(String pathToSkin) {
    File file = new File(pathToSkin);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
}

/**
 * @param assetManager
 * @param in
 * @param out
 * @param pathToSkin
 */
private void saveSkinToSdCard(String pathToSkin) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = assetManager.open(UCCW_TEST_SKIN_APK);
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(pathToSkin);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        in.close();
        in = null;

        out.flush();

        out.close();

        out = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @param pathToSkin
 */
private void startAppInstaller(String pathToSkin) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToSkin)),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent);
}

private boolean isSDcardAvailable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return state.contentEquals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
            || state.contentEquals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY);
}
}
```

I tried adding codes I found of people who asked similar questions, but like I said, I have hardly any knowledge of java and did the rest in xml. My ImageView2 has to link to a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonRepairSkin).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showInstallableSkins();
                }

            });
    findViewById(R.id. imageView2).setOnClickListener(
        new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "in onClick");
                 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url_to_website));
                 startActivity(browserIntent);
             }

    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me, where in the Java code I need to add this. I'm sorry, but everytime I try, I fail

Comment: Right below setContentView(R.layout.main) in your activity code. If you have compilation problems or errors when running the app, copy the error message so I can guide you better. You'll get there ! ;)

Comment: Problem: I have no errors in compilation, however I tested it out in the emulator, it doesn't do anything when I click on it :/

Comment: You can try adding android:clickable="true" to your ImageView in the xml. Just to make sure the onClickListener is called, add a log in the  onClick method before creating the Intent, like so : Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "in onClick"); and see if that shows in your LogCat.

Comment: ` @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  context = this;
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  
  findViewById(R.id. imageView2).setOnClickListener(
       new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=penhoat.design.gs5free&hl=nl"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }

   });` That is my .java now

Comment: Where do I need the log in the onClick method??

Comment: findViewById(R.id. imageView2).setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "in onClick");

Comment: I know I'm a real pain. I added the: Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "in onClick"); line above Intentbrowser... etc. It gives me the error: log cannot be resolved

Comment: add this import : import android.util.Log;

Comment: I'm really sorry, could you show me, in code tags, how it should look like now, cause it's now an error mess

Comment: See my edited answer. Don't forget to add the import declaration after the other ones in the java code.

Comment: EDIT: I'm so sorry man. It just didn't work in the emulator, it works perfectly fine on my phone when compiled to an app! If I could give u a medal I would, great man!

Comment: Lol, glad you made it work in the end! From what I see, you're making UCCW skins, that's very cool :) If you plan on going further with Android development, you should consider learning java and the sdk, it's actually pretty interesting. If you need it, I could recommend a few learning resources, just hit me on G+ (you'll find a link on my SO profile) and we'll get you going ;)

Answer (score 0):

just add a click listener for imageview and paste the below lines

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

and add internet permission

Comment: How do I add that, and where? Like I said, my knowledge of Java is extremely basic